# How can I achieve CSS gridlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, autolayout, android-constraintlayout

I am finding CSS Gridlayout alternative in Android to perform responsive structure. Layout should be multi dimensional and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

There is GridView in android and you can also use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and set the number of columns dynamically in the GridLayoutManager. You can also set the number of columns based on screen dimensions if you are thinking of responsiveness.

Comment: It should be responsive.. Like flex box layout but multi dimensional